# Why the curve plotted in OpenGL is more jagged than Matlab

Tags: matlab, opengl, plot

I have a set of points plotted both in the OpenGL and Matlab. However, the result seems quite different.
I use this code snippet to draw the curve in OpenGL

```
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT,GL_NICEST);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex3f(p[j].x, p[j].y, p[j].z);
glVertex3f(p[j + 1].x, p[j + 1].y, p[j + 1].z);
glEnd();
```

The result is

[image]

for the same set of data points plotted in the matlab. 
(I just using the plot() function in matlab)

[image]

After I zoomed in the figure of Matlab

[image]

I am curious that why the result will be so different.

I add the points below

```
 -122.155349    37.46875321
 -122.1553514   37.46874396
 -122.1553539   37.4687347
 -122.1553564   37.46872545
 -122.155359    37.46871622
 -122.1553617   37.46870702
 -122.1553645   37.46869783
 -122.1553673   37.46868867
 -122.1553702   37.46867953
 -122.1553731   37.46867041
 -122.1553761   37.46866131
 -122.1553792   37.46865223
 -122.1553823   37.46864317
 -122.1553855   37.46863412
 -122.1553887   37.4686251
 -122.155392    37.46861609
 -122.1553953   37.46860711
 -122.1553987   37.46859814
 -122.1554022   37.4685892
 -122.1554057   37.46858029
 -122.1554093   37.4685714
 -122.1554129   37.46856254
 -122.1554167   37.4685537
 -122.1554205   37.4685449
 -122.1554243   37.46853613
 -122.1554283   37.46852739
 -122.1554323   37.46851869
 -122.1554364   37.46851004
 -122.1554406   37.46850143
 -122.155445    37.46849287
 -122.1554494   37.46848437
 -122.1554539   37.46847593
 -122.1554586   37.46846756
 -122.1554634   37.46845927
 -122.1554684   37.46845107
 -122.1554735   37.46844298
 -122.1554789   37.46843501
 -122.1554844   37.46842719
 -122.1554902   37.46841956
 -122.1554962   37.46841216
-122.1553856    37.468759
-122.1553879    37.46875006
-122.1553903    37.46874112
-122.1553928    37.46873219
-122.1553953    37.46872329
-122.155398     37.4687144
-122.1554007    37.46870554
-122.1554035    37.46869671
-122.1554063    37.4686879
-122.1554092    37.46867911
-122.1554122    37.46867034
-122.1554152    37.46866158
-122.1554183    37.46865285
-122.1554214    37.46864414
-122.1554246    37.46863545
-122.1554278    37.46862677
-122.1554311    37.46861812
-122.1554345    37.46860949
-122.1554379    37.46860088
-122.1554414    37.46859229
-122.1554449    37.46858373
-122.1554485    37.4685752
-122.1554522    37.4685667
-122.1554559    37.46855822
-122.1554597    37.46854978
-122.1554636    37.46854137
-122.1554676    37.468533
-122.1554716    37.46852467
-122.1554758    37.46851638
-122.15548      37.46850814
-122.1554843    37.46849996
-122.1554888    37.46849183
-122.1554933    37.46848377
-122.155498     37.46847579
-122.1555029    37.46846789
-122.1555079    37.46846009
-122.155513     37.46845241
-122.1555184    37.46844486
-122.155524     37.46843749
-122.1555298    37.46843034
```

Comment: I think it's because you zoomed in on the openGL window

Comment: @freak, However, even after I zoomed the figure in matlab, I think it still maintains reasonable shape

Comment: I think you code is buggy! I dont see more than 25 points in the figure.

Comment: @mmostajab, Sorry, I just upload a snapshot of portion of the figure

Comment: @Diame can you provide me the points so I can draw them with my code?

Comment: @mmostajab Sure, Thank you I added it.

Comment: @Diame you can put the points in a code block so it wont make your question too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GL_LINE_SMOOTH is an optional feature and many OpenGL implementations don't implement it. You should use full screen antialiasing (FSAA) instead. In modern OpenGL implementations this is done through multisampling. So you need to request a multisample window framebuffer format and enable multisampling with glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that Matlab is anti-aliasing the results, whereas opengl won't perform anti-aliasing unless you expressly request it (or write your own anti-aliasing function in a shader). Opengl would naturally generate more "blocky" results since it has to align to pixels.

Comment: That is reason I add    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH); and glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT,GL_NICEST); here. It does not help?

Comment: @Diame If you want to enable anti-aliasing, you have to enable multisampling:
https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling

Comment: @Diame: GL_LINE_SMOOTH is an optional feature and many OpenGL implementations don't implement it. You should use full screen antialiasing (FSAA) instead. In modern OpenGL implementations this is done through multisampling. So you need to request a multisample window framebuffer format and enable multisampling with glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);